# empty line appears while merging different file contents in shell script

Tags: shell, find, exec, cat

I wrote a shell script to merge some files' contents.  I created directories f1,f2,d1,d2, and files under those, and need to merge all the files contents:

```
f1 has file with contents "--this is new text from f1 ----"
f2 -- " --this is text from f2 ----"    
d1 -- " --this is new text from d1 ---"
d2 -- "---this is new text from d2 ---"
```

Script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home/me/f1  /home/me/f2  /home/me/d1  /home/me/d2  \
    -type f \
    -exec cat {} \; \
    -exec echo \; > /home/me/result/op.txt
```

The output is :

```
--this is new text from f1 ----

--this is text from f2 ----
--this is new text from d1 ---
---this is new text from d2 ---
--this is new text from f1 ----

--this is text from f2 ----
---this is new text from d2 ---
```

After file f1's contents, it adds one empty line.
I want merged contents without any empty lines in between. What are the changes I need to do in the above command?
Any help would be appreciated in advance.

Comment: Assuming your version of `find` can perform multiple `-exec` options, why *wouldn't* `-exec echo \;` produce empty lines?

Comment: Thanks for adding some of your script. To me, it's not clear where "-- this is new text from f1 ----" etc are coming from. There is clearly no code that is making that test and creating that output. Is this the content of the files?  For that matter, where is the 1 bit of specified output `"Both are present"`? You'll do better if you restrict your question and code to just the portion of your problem that solves " want merged contents without any empty line in between" . Maybe look at `man diff` (and search for various answers that use that). Good luck..

Comment: for simplicity i have modified and updated code please check the same

Comment: step back and get a simpler version of your problem to work. What do you have to do beyond `cat f1 f2 d1 d2`? Maybe `sort f1 f2 d1 d2` Or add Line numbers? `cat -n f1 f2 d1 d2 | sort -k1n` (or similar)? Once you have a solution to this, then passing your filenames to the  output process via `find` should be much easier to manage. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I need to merge files contents from f1,f2,d1,d2 directories into single file with NO empty line

Comment: OK, how about `sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d f1 f2 d1 d2 > output` ? This will delete any blank lines (or lines with just spaces or tabs) and put all data into the file `output`. Good luck.

Comment: sed command delete blank lines but i want to combine above find cmd with sed to get required output so how can i add sed in the above query?